# Merged types in TypeScript behave differently

Tags: typescript

I have the following example code:

```
interface Task {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

interface Context {
  tasks: Task[];
  z: number;
}

export type MoreContext<T extends string> = {
  [key in T]: {
    c: string;
  }[];
} & {
  x: string;
  y: string;
};

type C = Context & MoreContext<'tasks'>;

const exampleFn = (props: C) => {
  props.tasks[0].a;
  props.tasks[0].b;
  // All good here
  props.tasks[0].c;
  props.tasks.map((t) => {
    t.a;
    t.b;
    // TS error: c does not exist on Task
    t.c;
  });
};
```

I know merging types that way has its downsides, but why does it work to directly access `task[0]` with its types when using `.map()` is giving a compiler error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing what we call [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) in typescript.

You are experiencing what is considered a design limitation of TypeScript. Intersections of array types behave strangely and are not recommended. See [microsoft/TypeScript#41874](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41874) for an authoritative answer.